# Is a partly-upgraded magic item usable?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, crafting

Frank The Fighter has a set of +2 full plate. He's on a long journey with Cathy The Crafter and wants her to upgrade his armor to +3, using the rules for crafting while adventuring.

The cost difference is 5K GP, which translates to twenty days of actual time, or ten if Cathy takes the +5 DC to accelerate it.

Outside the 4 hours/day when Cathy is working on the armor, can Frank still wear it as regular +2 armor, or is it unusable until she completes the upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There are no rules for this

The [magic item creation rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Item-Creation) make no mention of the item being unusable while being upgraded. So you can expect to see *table variation* on that, as each GM will rule it however they best see it.

However, if you consider that creating a magic item requires you to first obtain the mundane version of it, and then apply the reagents and required enchantments to turn it magical, then it wouldn't be unthinkable that while someone is working on enchanting your magic item for you, especially if they require to write runes or apply sensitive materials (*magic supplies*) to it, that the item should be unavailable during the process.

Personally, I would say that the item is unusable for the enchanting period, with a small risk of destroying the entire process should you ignore that and use it anyway. Like if you are critically hit, or critically fumble a check using the item, or some other appropriate circumstance. But I wouldn't simply waste the creator's efforts simply because the item is being used while not fully upgraded, as that affects the [Wealth by Level](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/#Table-Average-Magic-Item-Values) of the group and makes them waste time unnecessarily, which goes against the *Rule of Cool* to me.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes

First of all, when crafting an item you don't have to spend the days consecutively. You can craft half of it (though you pay the gold up front), go off to adventure for a while, then finish it later:

> The caster can work for up to 8 hours each day. He cannot rush the process by working longer each day, but the days need not be consecutive, and the caster can use the rest of his time as he sees fit.

The only limit is that you can't start work on a *new* item until you finish this one:

> A character can work on only one item at a time. If a character starts work on a new item, all materials used on the under-construction item are wasted.

If you're in a hurry, you can craft the item in the middle of an adventure, though it's sub-optimal:

> If the caster is out adventuring, he can devote 4 hours each day to item creation, although he nets only 2 hours' worth of work. This time is not spent in one continuous period, but rather during lunch, morning preparation, and during watches at night. ... Work that is performed in a distracting or dangerous environment nets only half the amount of progress (just as with the adventuring caster).

Nothing in these rules suggests that a partially-upgraded item is not usable. It retains its old properties until the item creation process is complete, whereupon it gains the new upgraded abilities.

You can still wear the item while it's being upgraded. You're not working on it constantly, only in patches of downtime during the adventuring day. No rule says you have to take an item off to work on it, but even if the DM says you do, the character could just hand you their helmet for an hour while you work on it, or you borrow their gauntlet while they're eating, and so on.

Sources: [Magic Item Creation](https://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html) (Core), [Magic Item Creation](https://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCampaign/campaignSystems/magicItemCreation.html) (Ultimate Campaign)

Comment: This is how I'd always interpreted it. But my GM's position is that "you're taking the item apart and rebuilding it" (in magical terms, not necessarily the physical item), and I haven't found anything that explicitly contradicts either interpretation.

Comment: Ah, then he's applying the Golden Rule: _The DM is always right_. Unfortunately for your magic item, the DM is free to invent rules, or even overturn existing rules.